# PHP-cookie not saving

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm currently implementing some stuff with session & cookies, but the cookies aren't stored on my computer. Accordingly the session could not be retrieved.

```
session_start();        // returns true
var_dump($_SESSION);    // array(0) {}
var_dump($_COOKIE);     // array(0) {}
$_SESSION['test'] = 5;
setcookie('aaa', '111', strtotime('+30 days'));
die;
```

Reloading the page should display non-empty arrays. But they are always empty.
Also there is no cookie displayed on the cookies-tab in Firebug.
I use another domain on the same server that works fine with sessions.

Any ideas?

Comment: try setting path (4th param) to `/` and if that doesn't work, set domain to `.yoursite.com`

Comment: There cannot be any output before setcookie is called from what I know

Comment: How do the corresponding `Set-Cookie` header fields look like? If there are none, is there some output before this code?

Comment: @Mark: thx, but that does not work either

Comment: In firebug there is a 'Net' tab. Please open that and copy/paste the response headers. Also put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

Comment: @Dharman: that did the trick: i had a single space char before the opening php tag, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Be sure not to have any output before calling any functions that make use of headers.
So try this instead:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 5;
setcookie('aaa', '111', strtotime('+30 days'));
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Comment: tks for the "Be sure not to have any output before calling any functions that make use of headers" ;)